# Inflection acronym not working well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acronym

I have a problem using inflections.acronym in my project because they have almost the same name

Basically, I have 2 Controllers: SEController and TSEController. They are completelly different.

I added the following lines im my inflections:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'SE'
  inflect.acronym 'TSE'
end
```

When I try to access my SEController it works fine, but when I try to acces my TSEController it says:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.11)
irb(main):001:0> SEController
=> SEController
irb(main):002:0> TSEController
NameError: uninitialized constant TSEController
from (irb):2
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

If I remove the following line,

```
inflect.acronym 'SE'
```

my TSEController works fine

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.11)
irb(main):001:0> TSEController
=> TSEController
```

What can I do about it?

Comment: WHat will happen if you add them other way around, first 'TSE' then 'SE'?

Comment: I've already tried it, but didn't work too.

Comment: Congratulations! You found a bug: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9882

Comment: Isn't there another way to do it?